# How do I further reduce leaves from being tracked throughout the house?

Tags: cleaning, backyard

Our house has a screened-in-porch that leads to a deck that leads to the backyard.  We've been pretty happy with our ability to reduce mud and leaf tracking by raking/mowing and using simple mats at the door between the porch and the deck, and making sure to take our shoes off on the mats.

We just got a puppy so we are going back and forth through this route 7-10 times per day.  The mats are no longer enough to prevent leaves from being tracked, because so many leaves are being brought in that they get on our socks or feet and just generally get moved around a lot since we are walking among the leaves so often.  It's not a huge number of leaves being tracked through the house, but it's enough that we find ourselves having to clean the floors a few times per day.

What else can we do to prevent tracking leaves throughout the house that won't require additional labor each of the 7-10 times we go out?

We do rake and mow, but even then leaves are constantly falling this time of year.  We vacuum the area once every day or two and that just isn't doing enough.

Comment: Probably the only thing is to take a minute or two and brush the puppies paws off.  Might even be able train the puppy to brush their paws off on the mat.

Comment: keep a leaf blower plugged in by the door. I once rigged one up to a motion detector fixture set on test mode to blast your feet as you walked by.

Comment: @dandavis   A Rube Goldberg fan?